# Is there a best time to play Tablet of Time's Dawn?

Tags: deck-building, ascension

The card Tablet of Time's Dawn (ToTD) states:

> You may banish this Construct to take an additional turn after this
>   one.

Is there a best<sup>1</sup> time to use the card's ability? I see three possibilities (my definition of the three phases are somewhat vague):

- **Early game** (basically as soon as possible): if you're trying to thin your deck (e.g. by using Shade of the Black Watch, which lets you banish a card in your hand or discard pile), playing ToTD now might get you a more effective (more runes or power per card) deck than your opponent.
- **Mid-game** (you'll get several opportunities to use cards bought in this phase): playing ToTD now, will give you two shots at buying good cards in the card row, thus denying your opponent them.
- **Late-game** (your last, or second-to-last round): playing ToTD late in the game will give you two chances to use your deck to the best of its ability.

This is of course barring the occasion that you get e.g. Hedron Link Device and Reclamax in addition to ToTD, for the possibility of infinite turns. Let's assume the game is played with 60 VP and you're playing against one opponent.

<sub>1. Where best is defined as what gives you the greatest likelyhood of winning the game.</sub>

Comment: I personally use it after I have a deck capable of buying it again on the extra turn, to get infinite turns out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no best time to use that ability to increase your odds of of winning. The thing to remember with cards like this is that a lot of it will depend on how the overall game is progressing. This includes the skill level of your opponents and what mix of cards are coming out

Early/Mid game I find it best used when there is one or more cards in the center that you want to get or prevent others from getting. This works great when paired with cards that have abilities to acquire one or more cards from the center/deck. Even better if you can stack your deck or otherwise ensure you will have those abilities.

End game it is similar but also ensuring that you will be able to get at least get the two honor back that you would lose from banishing it.

Last thing to remember is that even with a deck that can regularly pull out some very good turns it is possible for the extra turn to be a dud. It has happened to me where I end up drawing my entire deck (plus all the cards I acquired that turn) and end up with crap for the following turn.